# Activator.CreateInstance | Create Page.xaml instance with a string

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I created some dynamic buttons with a name the same as xaml pages.

Example of the button is Button `x:Name="btnOne"` and I have a page with the same name `btnOne.xaml`.

What I want the code to do is that every time I click on a dynamically created button(btnOne, btnTwo, tbnthree, ...), it would open a wpf page in my `mainWindow.frmContent` with the same name like (`btnOne.xaml`, `btnTwo.xaml`, `btnThree.xaml`,...)

I have this code below but it gives me this error.

> Could not load type 'btnOne' from assembly MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

```
    public void dynBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.frmContent.Content = Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", btn.Name);
    }
```

Comment: You probably need the namespace.

Comment: Thanks, but where should I place/add the namespace?

Comment: In the typename.

Comment: It worked! :D Thanks a lot @SLaks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the full namespace in the typename parameter.